# Tapped Slideshow Image From JSON

Tags: c#, json, image, uwp, slideshow

I have a picture slideshow that when the picture was tapped by the user and if the url in json no "#", it will go to the url address.
JSON:
[image: JSON]

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="topBanner" Source="images/new (3.0)/banner/MI-W10-banner-1366-01.png" Tapped="topBanner_Tapped" />
```

Code:

```
DispatcherTimer playlistTimer1a = null;
List<string> Images1a = new List<string>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ImageSource1a();
}

private async void ImageSource1a()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                httpClientHandler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                string urlPath = "http://";
                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("platform","win"),     
                };
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                //JsonObject jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();

                JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

                foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
                {

                    JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                   string image = groupObject1["image"].GetString();
                    string url = groupObject1["url"].GetString();
                    Images1a.Add(image);
                }


                    playlistTimer1a = new DispatcherTimer();
                    playlistTimer1a.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);
                    playlistTimer1a.Tick += playlistTimer_Tick1a;
                    topBanner.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Images1a[0]));
                    playlistTimer1a.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                RequestException();
            }
        }

 int count1a = 0;

void playlistTimer_Tick1a(object sender, object e)
        {
           if (Images1a != null)
            {

                if (count1a < Images1a.Count)
                    count1a++;

                if (count1a >= Images1a.Count)
                    count1a = 0;

                ImageRotation1a();
            }
        }

private async void ImageRotation1a()
        {
            OpacityTrans1.Begin();
        }

 private void topBanner_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //I have to confused to add this code
           //Can anyone help me to add this code
        }
```

How, when the slideshow image tapped by the user, it will go to url address on JSON (when the address url not '#')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of improvements to be made to the code. I recommend you read a bit more about DataBinding and MVVM.

However, I will try to help you with the code, as-is:

First, you need to ensure you maintain all the data from JSON so you can use it later. Instead of having a List for the image URLs you need to have a structure to hold both urls:

```
public struct DataItem
{
   public string ImageUrl {get;set;}
   public string Url {get;set;}
}
```

Then declare your list as:

```
List<DataItem> Images1a = new List<DataItem>();
```

When you build you list, create DataItem instances and add them to the list

```
foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
{

    JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();

    var dataItem = new DataItem();
    dataItem.ImageUrl = groupObject1["image"].GetString();
    dataItem.Url = groupObject1["url"].GetString();

    Images1a.Add(dataItem);
 }
```

Finally, when you tap an image, find the url based on the index:

```
private async void topBanner_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tappedItem = Images1a[count1a];
    if (tappedItem.Url != "#")
    {
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(tappedItem.Url));        
    }
}
```

You can read more about how to launch URIs from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701480.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)